# eapolclient process using 30GB of memory?

Tags: memory, macos

I’m using a brand new Retina MacBook Pro, 15-inch, Mid 2015  running OSX 10.11.1 with 16GB RAM.
I received a low memory warning, asking me to close unused applications.
When I checked Activity Monitor, I saw the the *eapolclient* process had used 30GB of RAM.

Is this normal?  I was running Adobe Audition, Tweetbot, and Chrome - about 7 tabs, none of these apps were doing any intensive processing at the time…

Any suggestions as to what is going on?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The eapolclient is used by Mac OS X to connect to 802.1x secured wireless networks.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least three processes running wild:

*eapolclient*:       probably related to 802.1x protected networks
*CCXProcess*:   related to Adobe Creative Cloud
*CCXLibrary*:     related to Adobe Creative Cloud

The last two [obviously occur](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8219606?tstart=0#8219606) after the update to Creative Cloud 3.4.0.180. A staff member of the Adobe forum advises to update to Creative Cloud 3.4.0.181.

To solve your problem for now try to quit or kill the three processes in *Activity Monitor*. Then try to quit all other running apps graciously (by quitting them from their menubar), restart the machine and check if it's still the same.

---

There is some evidence that the Creative Cloud problems are related to corrupted preferences files. You may try to create a dummy user, log-in with your CC credentials and check if the problem persists.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you.  I'm updating CC now... Any idea about what to do about the other one?

Comment: @tomh It may be related to the rogue CC version . Is your Mac connected to a RADIUS server?

Comment: @tomh, After a reboot does `eapolclient` still consume an absurd amount of memory?